# CSS - How to line up divs and text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style some contnent to look like this image:
[image]

I need `Text Item 1` and `Text Item 3` to be be completely aligned as well as `Text Item 2` and `Text item 4`. There should be space between teh left and right side items.

Ideally I would like to do this in flex box but would work even in basic css but I can't understand how to do this.

```css
.outterBox {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block; 
}

.temp {
  justify-content: space-between; 
}
```

```html
<div class="outterBox">
  <div class="inline-block">
    <img src="https://404store.com/2017/12/08/Er-weird-O-o-random-23398022-600-678.jpg" width="50"/>
  </div>
  <div class="inline-block">
    <div>
      <span>Text Item 1</span>
      <span>Text Item 2</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Text Item 3</span>
      <span>Text Item 4</span>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this in my opinion would be to make both the image and the two sets of text siblings. From here, all you would need to do is turn the container into a flex element and have it align and separate the children with:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
text-align: center;
```

Then simply give the (immediate) children the following:

```
flex: 1;
```

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.flex {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex > * {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <img src="https://404store.com/2017/12/08/Er-weird-O-o-random-23398022-600-678.jpg" width="50" />
  <div>
    <div>Text Item 1</div>
    <div>Text Item 2</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Text Item 3</div>
    <div>Text Item 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like that if you want to make it simply way without flex:

```
<div class="outer-box">
  <img class="thumb" src="..."/>

  <div class="inner-box">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="left">Text Item 1</div>
      <div class="right">Text Item 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="left">Text Item 1</div>
      <div class="right">Text Item 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And css:

```
.outer-box {
  border-radius: 1px black solid;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img.thumb {
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.inner-box {
  width: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.left, .right {
  display: inline-block;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it. This will give nice vertical spacing too.

```css
.outer-box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
}

.img-wrap {
  flex: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

.text-wrap {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.space-between {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-box">
  <div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="https://404store.com/2017/12/08/Er-weird-O-o-random-23398022-600-678.jpg" width="50"/>
  </div>
  <div class="text-wrap">
    <div class="space-between">
      <span>Text Item 1</span>
      <span>Text Item 3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="space-between">
      <span>Text Item 2</span>
      <span>Text Item 4</span>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here are some basic CSS, hope it will help you.

```css
.outterBox {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  height: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.temp {
  justify-content: space-between; 
}
.inline-block .first_column{
margin-left:10
}
.inline-block .second_column{
margin-left:50
}
.inline-block .row{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="outterBox">
  <div class="inline-block">
    <img src="https://404store.com/2017/12/08/Er-weird-O-o-random-23398022-600-678.jpg" width="50"/>
  </div>
  <div class="inline-block">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="first_column">Text Item 1</span>
      <span class="second_column">Text Item 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <span class="first_column">Text Item 3</span>
      <span class="second_column">Text Item 4</span>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All Solutions here are fails, the only one that works is mine, but don't get mad guys, it's because I am the best :))

https://codepen.io/Max_Muster/pen/KKwZEvm

Your HTML should look like this:

```
<div class="outterBox">
    <img src="https://404store.com/2017/12/08/Er-weird-O-o-random-23398022-600-678.jpg" width="50"/>
  <div class="inline-block">
    <div>
      <span class="up left">Text Item 1</span>
      <span class="up right">Text Item 2</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="down left">Text Item 3</span>
      <span class="down right">Text Item 4</span>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Your CSS should look like this :

```
:root{
  --pic-height: 100px;
  --pic-width: 89px;
  --span-width: 100px;
  --justify-content: 50px; /* space-between */
  --dist-pic2div: 50px;
  --outerbox-padding: 20px;
}
img {
  position:relative;
  height: VAR(--pic-height);
  width: auto;
  padding-right: VAR(--dist-pic2div);
}
span{
  border:1px solid #00ff00;
  width: VAR(--span-width);
}
span.up {
  float:up;
}
span.left{
  float:left;
  left:0;
}
span.right{
  float:right;
  right:0;
}
span.down {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
.outterBox {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: VAR(--outerbox-padding);
  width: CALC( VAR(--dist-pic2div) + VAR(--justify-content) + ( 2 * VAR(--span-width) ) + VAR(--pic-width) + VAR(--outerbox-padding) );
}

.inline-block {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  height: VAR(--pic-height);
  width: CALC((2 * VAR(--span-width)) + VAR(--justify-content));
}
```

and you get something like this :

[check out this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r13Q3.jpg)